# Positioning a div in js

Tags: javascript

Wonder if anyone could give me some guidance. I'm trying to reposition a div based on:

if fpd-actions-wrapper has a class of fpd-pos-outside then position in body.
else position (as below) in main wrapper.

```
//set action button to specific position
var _setActionButtons = function(pos) {

    fpdInstance.$mainWrapper.append('<div class="fpd-actions-wrapper fpd-pos-'+pos+'"></div>');

    var posActions = instance.currentActions[pos];

    for(var i=0; i < posActions.length; ++i) {

        var actionName = posActions[i],
            $action = $actions.children('[data-action="'+actionName+'"]');


        fpdInstance.$mainWrapper.children('.fpd-actions-wrapper.fpd-pos-'+pos).append($action.clone());
    }

};
```

I've tried below and it does get .fpd-actions-wrapper out of the main wrapper but it's empty - can't work out the last line.

```
 //set action button to specific position
 var _setActionButtons = function(pos) {
 $body = $('body');
    $body.append('<div class="fpd-actions-wrapper fpd-pos-'+pos+'"></div>');

    var posActions = instance.currentActions[pos];

    for(var i=0; i < posActions.length; ++i) {

        var actionName = posActions[i],
            $action = $actions.children('[data-action="'+actionName+'"]');

        fpdInstance.$mainWrapper.children('.fpd-actions-wrapper.fpd-pos- 
        '+pos).append($action.clone());
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add position:aboslute; top:10px; left:10px to you div tag. Only divisions with fixed or absolute positions can be moved pro-grammatically. You must define x (distance to left side) and y (distance to top of screen) motion independently.
 I only defined the 'top' position. You need to add a 'left' point of reference as well. It may not be a simple 'left:'+pos+'px;', so I did not add that code for you except in the div tag.
Notice that the actual commands to change position are very much 'css' like. The div tag uses css syntax, so must your code.

//set action button to specific position
var _setActionButtons = function(pos) {

```
fpdInstance.$mainWrapper.append('<div class="fpd-actions-wrapper fpd-pos-'top:'+pos+'px; fpd-pos-'left:'+pos+'px;"></div>');

var posActions = instance.currentActions['top':+pos+"px;"];

for(var i=0; i < posActions.length; ++i) {

    var actionName = posActions[i],
        $action = $actions.children('[data-action="'+actionName+'"]');


    fpdInstance.$mainWrapper.children('.fpd-actions-wrapper.fpd-pos-':'+pos'px;').append($action.clone());
}
```

};

Comment: Thanks for the help. I want to take it out of the main wrapper though completely rather than position it within it.

Comment: Delete ALL references to your wrapper and its div class. The div tag does not need a 'class' to control position, just an id of your choice. For this to work your object needs a div wrapper of some type or id. Technically your code is outside of the div tags already. Even something as ghostly as innerHTML needs a div wrapper. You still need to control position by div id or class regardless.

Comment: Do not forget to include your default object position and other styling with a style tag inside the div tag. You cannot do this without a div tag, whether your code is inside the div tag or outside. You will need to clean up and redo your code.